# How does a GlassFish cluster find active IIOP endpoints?

Tags: glassfish, jvm, cluster-computing, iiop

I have a curiosity and I was searching for it without any result. In GlassFish documentation it is written:

> If the GlassFish Server instance on which the application client is
>   deployed participates in a cluster, the GlassFish Server finds all
>   currently active IIOP endpoints in the cluster automatically. However,
>   a client should have at least two endpoints specified for
>   bootstrapping purposes, in case one of the endpoints has failed.

but I am asking myself how this list is created.

I've done some tests with a stand-alone client that is executed in a JVM and does some RMI calls on an application that is deployed in a GlassFish cluster and I can see from the logs that the IIOP endpoints list is completed automatically and it is set as *com.sun.appserv.iiop.endpoints* system property but if I stop a server instance or start another during the execution of the client the list remains the one that was created when the JVM was started.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish clustering is managed by the GMS (Group Management Service) which usually uses UDP Multicast, but can use TCP where that is not available.

See section 4 "Administering GlassFish Server Clusters" in the [HA Administration Guide (PDF)](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/ha-administration-guide.pdf)

> The Group Management Service (GMS) enables instances to participate in a cluster by
>   detecting changes in cluster membership and notifying instances of the changes. To
>   ensure that GMS can detect changes in cluster membership, a cluster's GMS settings
>   must be configured correctly.